# Local search and categorisation using tags in html

Tags: html, tags, meta

I have tried exhaustively to find information on this but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords so apologies if this has already been answered.
I'm sure this is a very basic function which has passed me by but I'm trying to find a way to categorise articles on my website by using meta tags or something similar.
The goal is to be able to click on any of the main links in my header and for a list containing a set of relevant articles to be displayed.
I'm guessing I'd use meta tags to define the category of each article but how would I get a clicked link to display all relevant pages under that tag?

Comment: Can you provide an example? A link or something else...

Comment: With a quick research, there is not built-in tag tool which perform this kind of behaviour. Instead, try to see further for any Frameworks which could provides this kind of element, or do it yourself ;) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you were to use jQuery then you could do something like this: (may not be 100% just an example). as Zeratops states this is not something built in but can be accomplished with some other frameworks.

```
<a class='filterlink' data-catigory='catigory1'>click me to show all cat 1</a>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory1"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory1"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory1"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory1"></div>


<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory2"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory2"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory2"></div>
<div class='filterable' data-catigory="catigory2"></div>

$(function(){
    $('.filterlink').click(function(){
     var catigory = $(this).data('catigory');
     $(".filterable").hide();
     $(".filterable[data-catigory='"+catigory+"']").show();
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks workabyte. This looks promising. Just having a look a it now.